# How do I insert a circle inside another circle with Piecewise?

Tags: plotting, functions, piecewise

I need to create two circles, where one circle is inside the other using the `Piecewise` function. So far I have

```
f[x_, y_, z_, a_] := Piecewise[{{1, x^2 + y^2 <= 30}, {0, x^2 + y^2 > 30},}
```

I know by changing the radius, I can have a circle inside the other, but how do I go about it using `Piecewise`?

Comment: What is $a$?  What is $z$?  *Why* use `Piecewise`?  And do you want a `Circle` or a `Disk`?

Comment: @IrisGarza  How did you mean to apply `Piecewise`?

Comment: Why not use `ParametricPlot`, or if you need just two full circles, than simple `Graphics` directive.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
PolarPlot[Piecewise[{{1, θ < 2 Pi}, {2, θ > 2 Pi}}], {θ, 0, 4 Pi}]

Module[{i = 1}, % /. x_Line :> {ColorData[3][i++], x}]
```

[image]

Also implicit curves can be given in a list:

```
ContourPlot[
 {x^2 + y^2 == 1, x^2 + y^2 == 2^2},
 {x, -E, E}, {y, -E, E},
]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It should be noted that constructing "chimeric" curves, given their implicit Cartesian equations, is not too hard, and does not need a piecewise construction. Recall that if $f(x,y)=0$ and $g(x,y)=0$ are two non-identical curves, then the curve $f(x,y)\,g(x,y)=0$ is a curve composed of the two other curves. Thus, using the Wizard's example:

```
ContourPlot[(x^2 + y^2 - 1) (x^2 + y^2 - 2^2) == 0, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}]
```

[image: two circles joined together]

Answer (score 1):

```
f[r1_, r2_] := Graphics[
  {Circle[{0, 0}, r1],
   Circle[{0, 0}, r2]}
  ]
```